# Salesforce push notifications not triggering in-app event listeners on Android

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, push-notification, salesforce-sdk-android

We are sending our push notifications from Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile Push and they are being delivered to both Android and iOS.

We are also listening in on those push notifications inside our code to trigger our desired outcome after a notification has been clicked.

These listeners are working as expected for iPhone, but even though Android is successfully receiving the notification -> **it does not trigger any push notification listeners/callbacks.**

The problem does not exist if i use any other tool to send the notification such as:

- [fcm tester](https://testfcm.com/)

- [expo notification tool](https://testfcm.com/)

This leads me to believe that it is a configuration problem for SMC Mobile Push.

I have already made sure that our ServerKey inside SMC->MobilePush->Administration is set to the same value as our FCM Server Key.

What else can be done?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Open a support case.